# How to get the user ID if the user is exist in the database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a database consists of 2 tables with one to many relationship between them .

The first table "data" has (name , phone , personid) columns.

The second table "links" has (linkid , link , personid) columns.

I want to insert a new link to the links of a person if he already exists in the data table .

```
$statement = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM data WHERE name = :sname AND phone = :sphone");  
$statement->execute(array('sname' => $name , 'sphone' => $phone));  
$count = $statement->rowCount();


if($count > 0){    
$st = $connect->prepare("SELECT personid FROM data WHERE name = :sname AND phone = :sphone");   
$id = $st->execute(array('sname' => $name , 'sphone' => $phone));
```

I want to get the ID if the user if he exist to use it to insert a new link to his links , So how could I get the ID?

Comment: For clarification, you want the function to get the `personid` or you want the query to check for existing data?

Comment: If using PDO, you will need to put a colon in front of the bind names.

Comment: I already check that the user exist or not , after that I want to get his ID by his name and phone

Comment: @NigelRen If you mean the bind names inside the `execute()`, the colon is optional

Comment: Check my answer, just comment there for clarifications or questions in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are expecting one column only, you can use [`fetchColumn()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php):

```
$st = $connect->prepare("SELECT personid FROM data WHERE name = :sname AND phone = :sphone");   
$st->execute(array('sname' => $name , 'sphone' => $phone));
$personID = $st->fetchColumn();
```

You can also use [`fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) if you are expecting a single row return:

```
$st = $connect->prepare("SELECT personid FROM data WHERE name = :sname AND phone = :sphone");   
$st->execute(array('sname' => $name , 'sphone' => $phone));
$row= $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$personID = $row['personid'];
```

`$personID` should hold the data from `personid` column returned from the query

***Note:*** If you already set the fetch style in your connection, you can omit `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`